# In Google cache, no images are showing

Tags: google-chrome, mobile-website

In this [google cache snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU6mT.png), I don't understand that why image not showing in this mobile app development website. No images are showing after cache. I have many websites but this website has the issue. There are must be some issue in code. Anyone please help me.

Link: https://www.webapplay.com/

Comment: Voting to close since this just has links to pictures of code not  code ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

This happens in case when the page is down or temporary timeout occurs. The meaning of **google's cache snapshot** is that Google's Chrome has saved a basic HTML file of the page (in your case https://www.webapplay.com/). This problem would not occur as of now.
Also its good if you try clearing your browser's cached data to clear the message.

Comment: Just saw your answer I have to try it.